# Fragment Back Navigation Exiting to Home Screen - Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation

I have one fragment in an activity, I can launch the fragment using FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction, but when I try to navigate back to the Activity via the back button, the app exits.

Here is my fragment creation & transaction in the Activity class:

```
DetailFragment df = new DetailFragment();

try {
    df.initFragment(jsonObject);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, df);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I also override onBackPressed()

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

With the above setup, one press of the back button exits to the home screen.

---

I also tried to modify onBackPressed() to do:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        fm.popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();  
    }
}
```

On this second version of onBackPressed(), it takes 2 back presses to go back to the home screen. Keep in mind I am trying to return to the original Activity.

Any suggestions?

P.S. I can add my fragment code if needed

Comment: What is your activity class extending? i.e., `ActionBarActivity`, `Activity`, etc?

Comment: @RogueBaneling activity class extends AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0):

Your second version of `onBackPressed()` requires 2 back presses to go back to the home screen. So it seems like `fm.popBackStack()` is getting called. Try replacing it with `popBackStackImmediate()`.

**Edit:**
When you are creating the fragment, try using the following instead of `.replace`:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, df);
```

If that still doesn't work, try:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    if (df.isVisible) {
        fm.beginTransaction().remove(df).commit();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();  
    }
}
```

(although this is less desirable as you are hard-coding what to remove).

Comment: I tried it out, still takes two back presses, and exits to home screen. I can't figure out why it doesn't go back to the main Activity

Comment: Hm, okay. Can you try using `fragmentTransaction.add` instead of `.replace`? If that still doesn't work, can you try using `fm.beginTransaction().remove(df).commit()` in your `onBackPressed`?

Comment: If neither of those help I will delete my answer as I am just guessing.

Comment: Haha don't delete the answer, it may help others to see what we already tried out. I changed .replace() to .add() and no changes... Then in onBackPressed() my fragment df is not a global variable so I can't remove df using remove(df).

Comment: I found my culprit! In my fragment class, onCreateView calls         getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_detail); so that I can update Textview fields and for some reason, that disallows the Fragment to return ot the main activity

Comment: That sounds like you are setting the Activity to have the exact same layout as the Fragment. It's possible that you **are** returning to the main activity but not realizing it because they have the exact same layout. But yes, calling `setContentView` from outside of an Activity's `onCreate` method is bad practice. Nice job finding your solution!

Answer (score 0):

The navigation was working, but in my Fragment's onCreateView I used setContentView() to the fragment view which painted the fragment view to the main activity, so it *appeared* that the back button would exit out if it was pressed twice, but it was actually returning to the main activity as it should, it just repainted the main activity so it wasnt possible to tell.

Thanks for the help @RogueBaneling !!

original code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
    fragmentView.setClickable(true);
    getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_detail);


    final TextView movieTitleText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.movie_title_text);
    movieTitleText.setText(title);

    // editing textView code... 

    return fragmentView;
}
```

into:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
    fragmentView.setClickable(true);


    final TextView movieTitleText = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.movie_title_text);
    movieTitleText.setText(title);

    // editing textView code... 

    return fragmentView;
}
```